How can I hide the first tick mark on a Y axis of an Excel bar chart?
I am using an Excel barchart (in Office 365) to show some data. Some of the data might be zero and some might not have a value. I want to show the difference by effectively starting the Y axis at -1 but also hide the value -1. Therefore when there is a value of 0 it will have a bar.
I am not sure if this is the right way of showing such values or if there is another method.

You can do it by setting the y-axis minimum value to -1 and using the format code
0;;0



